# Application-defined or object-defined error 1004

Tags: vba, excel

VBA is throwing the above given error on the line  `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i & "A" & LastCol - 1)`

What I am trying to do is actually to copy the `"A" & i` cell (in first iteration it's `A2`) to a range in the second worksheet named Sheet2.

```
Sub FindFill()

Dim DatesRange As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim TransposeThis As Range
Dim LastCol As Integer

If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Cells) > 0 Then
   LastColumn = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], _
   SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
   SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
End If


With Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set DatesRange = Range("B2" & LastCol)
End With
i = 1
Do While i <= ActiveSheet.Rows.Count
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i + 1).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i & "A" & LastCol - 1)
    i = i + 1
Loop




End


End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a ":" before "A"

```
Range("A" & i & ":A" & LastCol - 1)
```

**FOLLOWUP**

After I went through your comments, I saw lot of errors in your code

**1)** You have dimmed `i` as `Integer`. This can give you an error in Excel 2007 onwards if your last row is beyond 32,767. Change it to `Long` I would recommend having a look at this link.

**Topic**: The Integer, Long, and Byte Data Types

**Link**: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa164754%28v=office.10%29.aspx

**Quote from the above link**

> Integer variables can hold values between -32,768 and 32,767, while Long variables can range from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647

**2)** You are finding the Last Column But in Which Sheet? You have to fully qualify the path Like this.

```
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells) > 0 Then
       LastCol = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], _
       SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
       SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    End If
```

Same is the case with

```
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set DatesRange = Range("B2" & LastCol)
End With
```

You are missing a DOT before `Range`

This is the correct way...

```
.Range("B2....
```

Also `Range("B2" & LastCol)` will not give you the range that you want. See the code below on how to create your range.

**3)** You are using a variable `LastColumn` but using `LastCol`. I would strongly advise using `Option Explicit` I would also recommend having a look at this link (SEE POINT 2 in the link).

**Topic**: To ‘Err’ is Human

**Link**: http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/08/01/to-err-is-human/

**4)** What happens if there `.CountA(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells) = 0`? :) I would suggest you this code instead

```
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells) > 0 Then
       LastCol = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], _
       SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
       SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    Else
        MsgBox "No Data Found"
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

**5)** `ActiveSheet.Rows.Count` will not give you the last active row. It will give you the total number of rows in that sheet. I would recommend getting the last row of Col A which has data.

You can use this for that

```
With Sheets("Sheet")
    LastRow =.Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlup).row
End With
```

Now use `LastRow` instead of `ActiveSheet.Rows.Count` You also might want to use a `For Loop` so that you don't have to increment `i` every time. For example

```
For i = 1 to LastRow
```

**6)** Finally You should never use `End`. Reason is quite simple. It's like Switching your Computer using the POWER OFF button. The End statement stops code execution abruptly, without invoking the Unload, QueryUnload, or Terminate event, or any other Visual Basic code. Also the Object references held (if any) by other programs are invalidated.

**7)** Based on your image in Chat, I believe you are trying to do this? This uses a code which doesn't use any loops.

```
Option Explicit

Sub FindFill()
    Dim wsI As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet
    Dim DatesRange As Range
    Dim LastCol As Long, LastRow As Long

    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No Data Found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set wsI = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsO = Sheets("Sheet2")

    With wsI
        LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set DatesRange = .Range("B1:" & Split(Cells(, LastCol).Address, "$")(1) & 1)

        .Columns(1).Copy wsO.Columns(1)
        DatesRange.Copy
        wsO.Range("B2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, _
        xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, False, True

        .Range("B2:" & Split(Cells(, LastCol).Address, "$")(1) & LastCol).Copy
        wsO.Range("C2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hm. Great observation. I did fix that, however the same error still persists.

Comment: i = 1, and LastCol is the number of filled columns in the worksheet.

Comment: In my specific case, LastCol = 4, since I have only 4 columns.

Comment: But you are using `LastColumn` and `LastCol`?

Comment: Now I see. That's what happens when I just copy-paste code from other modules. :)

Comment: Thank you very much. Anyway - if I run the code, shouldn't it stop? Since I am using End to end the loop...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13295/discussion-between-speci-and-siddharth-rout)